# Can you convert asp.net WebForm controls to HTML?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, controls

I am looking for a way to convert WebForm controls to text.

Is it possible to do this:

```
TextBox tx = new TextBox();
tx.Text = "test";

string html = tx.HTML();
```

Where html would be:

```
<input type="text" value="test"/>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 var sb = new StringBuilder();
 var htw = new HtmlTextWriter(new System.IO.StringWriter(sb, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

 var tx = new TextBox {Text = "test"};
 tx.RenderControl(htw);
 var html = sb.ToString();
 Response.Write(html);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `RenderControl()` method
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htwek607(v=vs.80).aspx and get the string in Stream object.